# What engine are comparable to swap in a Kia Sorento 2.5l 2009

Tags: engine, kia, engine-swap, sorento

Oil pump has buggered my engine so looking for a replacement.
Have been told Hyundai would swap, but clueless as what year model year ect.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
My is 2009

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you planning on procuring and swapping this engine yourself or are you expecting to have a mechanic do it?

Comment: I have a mechanic to do the work. Just need to find the engine.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am failing to see a listing where a 2009 Kia Sorrento would even have a 2.5 litre engine. Maybe if you specified region (I assumed North America) it'd be easier to find.

In general, however, yes, a Hyundai engine of the same year and same code should fit, however, I'd stick to the Kia engine from the exact same model and year, just to minimize amount of potential modifications and related components that need to also be swapped.

Comment: Sorry. Thought this was a uk site. 
I’m in England. 
Thank though.

Comment: This is a global site, that's why it'd be useful to mention the region.